# Making Angular 6 php mysql api calls

Tags: php, mysql, angular

I'm new to the Angular World (I have been using Angularjs all the while).

I want to make a login app and would like to make an api call to the backend (the php and mysql server, running locally on my computer).

In Angularjs, I would write a service like:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
angular.module('module name').service('userService', user);

function user ($resource) {
return $resource('api/users', {}, {update: {method: PUT}});
}
})();
```

With that, I could make calls to the server by simply calling

```
 $onInit = function () {
       var user = new userService();
       user.$save(.....) //post request.
       user.$update(....) //put request.
    }
```

In angular, I see things are different. I can't seem to connect to the server using the same code I wrote for AngularJS.

Making an api call like:

```
this.http.post('api/users', userAccess.value).subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
}
```

gives me post http://localhost:3001/api/users 404 not found error.

PS. userAccess is the ReactiveForm formGroup object containing an email address and a password.

The api code sits in a folder under src folder, next to app folder. It has 3 files, api.php, rest.inc.php and the htaccess file. It's my own implementation of an api interface.

Here is my LoginComponent.ts..

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.sass']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    hide: boolean = true;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    userAccess: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
        email: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
        password: ['', [Validators.required]]
    })

    onSubmit = () => {
        this.http.post('api/users', 
            {
                username: this.userAccess.value.email,
                encryption: this.userAccess.value.password
            }
        ).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);            
        });        
    }

    getEmailMessage = () => {
        return this.userAccess.controls['email'].hasError('required')  ? 'Please enter an email address'  :  this.userAccess.controls['email'].hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' : '';
    }

}
```

And here is the folder structure..

[image]

Here is the snapshot of the api folder.. 
[image]

This is the error I get no matter what path I put... 
[image]

How should I go about doing this the right way?

Comment: can you post little more of your code? files you are importing etc.

Comment: are you using angular js or angular 6? as your code and whole description says you are using js but your question heading says otherwise

Comment: I'm using Angular 6. I was just illustrating how I used to make api calls in angularjs.

Comment: There is no need to show how you make call in angularjs post data relevant to question.

Comment: Post your component and service code, complete code please

Comment: @Exterminator I have updated the question and included the login component code. There's no service. I was just calling the api directly from the component.

Comment: file structure you are using? are you defining api folder in the same project or not?

Comment: @Exterminator If you take a look at the folder structure from the picture I uploaded, there's an *api* folder under src. Inside the api folder are 3 files as mentioned above.

Comment: @Exterminator when I put the api folder at the root of the project folder, and put the path in login component as http/localhost/project_name/api/users  the error is now different. Now the error says *Failed to load http://localhost/firstmarkweb/api/users: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is present on the requested resource. Origin "http://localhost:4200" is therefore not allowed access.*

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 404 error that does mean you are able to call HTTP service from your angular code. Please check whether the URL for your API is correct or not. (*Hint:* Use Browser tools)

In Angular, to access API it is recommended to create a separate service class which can be later injected wherever you require it e.g. component.

You can create service class using following CLI command

> ng g s NameOfYourService

Later int the constructor of your service simply inject a reference of HttpClient. Refer below example

```
constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient)
```

you can use this reference as shown below

```
public performUserLogin(cred:Credentials):Promise<void> {
   return this.httpClient.post<void>('http://yourhost:yourport/api_path', cred).toPromise();
}
```

Note you have choice to either return promise or Observable.

For more details you can go through the [official documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

Answer (score 0):

path you have defined here is incorrect.

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/project_name/api/api.php', 
            {
                username: this.userAccess.value.email,
                encryption: this.userAccess.value.password
            }
        ).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);            
        });
```

change the path of the api folder, bring it to the root folder(at the same level of e2e folder), then do as mentioned.

add these lines to the php file

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

and to get the data in post request use this

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Comment: What should it be?

Comment: see i have changed it. in which language your api's are defined? 
add a slashed before api

Comment: and please also if any error occur please post a image of the network adapter in inspect element

Comment: It's in php. I could post the code but it's quite too long.

Comment: no need for the code, check the path i have posted now!

Comment: Still gives the same error of *POST http://localhost:3001/api/users 404 (Not Found)*

Comment: the files in api folder are *api.php*, *rest.inc.php*, and *.htaccess*.. The rest.inc.php file handles all the security and api requests. The api.php has all the callable functions inside the Api Class which implements the Rest Class from the rest.inc.php file. One of the functions in api.php file is *users* which handles user login, register, update and delete methods. Hence this makes me able to get a user like api/users/2 to get a user with an id of 2. There are other functions in the api.php like students, classes, team etc. All of them are callable like a real rest api, retu

Comment: there's no file called users.php. It's a rest api and all urls are friendly. Maybe it should be *http://localhost/project_name/api/users* without the extension

Comment: Just so you know, the text after */api/* is actually the name of the function in the api.php file. The mapping is done in the *.htaccess* file. So /api/users actually calls a function named *users* in the api.php file.

Comment: can you attach the screen shot of the api folder

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot of the api folder

Comment: I have edited the code @Kingsley you can check for it. Check for the api link passing in the service code i have changed that too as according to the requirement. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the error log, you get this 404 because you are not calling the good url, you try to reach localhost:4200 but you want to call localhost:3001.

On localhost:4200 you certainly have your angular app running if you launched it using the "ng serve" command, because ng serve uses port 4200.

Since you are not specifying the full path in your post, it is trying to reach the url from where you are calling it, here 4200.

So to fix that you should specify the full path in your post like this:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3001/api/users', userAccess.value).subscribe(data => {console.log(data);}
```

this should fix it, at least it should call your php api.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I just added a proxy configuration and run the server on a different port